# What to call theory where next activity following a fun activity is also perceived as fun?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, social-psychology, emotion, mood

What is the name of the theory that states:

> "if someone is having fun beforehand, the next activity they do will also seem fun regardless of what the activity is."

so like continuing fun... Any similar theories is welcome. I heard about this theory from my lecturer but I can't remember the name of it.

Comment: That is more of a hypothesis than a theory. Might be something relevant to positive emotional bias.

Answer (score 1):

The most related experiment that I can think, is the one that people were willing to drink more water after seeing a happy face, because they evaluated the water as more positive. See full article bellow :

[Face Value: Hidden Smiles Influence Consumption And Judgment](http://ucsdnews.ucsd.edu/archive/newsrel/soc/WinkielmanFaces.asp).